# Is there was a way to specify in a kv file for Kivy NOT to render a widget at start-up?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I recently discovered that I can remove and add widgets in Kivy without having to create new ones by simply referring to their ids, for instance:

```
self.remove_widget(self.ids['my_button']) # Removes the widget
self.add_widget(self.ids['my_button'])    # Adds the previously removed widget
```

This is perfect for my program, as I will often need to add and remove the same buttons.

However, Kivy will render everything that I write in the accompanying kv file, and I only would like certain buttons to appear at certain preset instances. I was wondering if there was a way to specify in a kv file for kivy NOT to render a widget at start-up, and instead wait for instructions to do so.

I think that the above approach is faster than constantly creating and destroying new buttons and more elegant than storing the buttons as an `ObjectProperty`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **1** : Create class in .py and same named widget in .kv. After that , you can add this button to your layouts when you want. Just call that class in .py file in button clicks or on_enter functions or random functions.as you want. 

**2**: You can give id to your widgets in .kv file. For an example, your id: 'widgetidkv'. After that , create random named ObjectProperty in .py file: 'widgetidpy'. Lastly, define these connected between. Type **widgetidpy:widgetidkv** this in your .kv file [on same class]. After that, you can reference this widget in .py file easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the Widget, if its parent is  `FloatLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, by adding the following lines to its `kv` rule:

```
    size_hint: 0, 0
    pos: -1, -1
    opacity: 0
```

The `opacity` set to zero makes it invisible, and the `size_hint` and `pos` keep it from responding to touch events. So the widget is actually rendered, but with zero opacity and zero size.

Note that just setting `size` to zeros will not make all widgets invisible. A `Label` or `Button` will still draw its `text`.

Now you can remove the widget. If you want it to show you will need to adjust the `opacity`, `size_hint`, and `pos`.